# install xorg server

Tags: debian, xorg, configure

I have this problem when installing xorg-server.   (Installation from source)

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glproto >= 1.4.17 gl >= 9.2.0) were not met:

No package 'gl' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GL_CFLAGS
and GL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Do I have to install a package? If so, what package should I install?

Comment: After the ./configure command, I will encounter this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the depencies via command:
`apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-core`

But it's much easier to use the official debian source of the newest xserver-xorg-core from sid repo: https://packages.debian.org/sid/xserver-xorg-core